# Which is the easiest way to extend a Lisp with a small correction in the evaluation?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, racket, eval, dsl

I would like to try extending some Lisp (Scheme, Racket, Clojure, any) to run external commands as follows:

```
; having
(define foo ...)
(define bar ...)
; on command
(ls (foo bar) baz)
; this lisp should evaluate (foo bar) as usual, with result "foobar", then
(ls foobar baz)
; here "ls" is not defined
; instead of rising "undefined identifier" exception
; it must look for "ls" command in the directories
; in the "PATH" environment variable
; and launch the first found "ls" command
; with strings "foobar" and "baz" on input
```

I just want to run it anyhow, without carrying about correct conversion from lisp's data structures to strings or handling the exit code and the output of the command in `stdout/stderr`.

I think there is no way to extend it within normal environment (like catching the "undefined" exception all the time). The `eval` procedure of the interpreter itself must be changed.

Which Lisp is the best to extend it like this and how is it done? Maybe there already exists a project performing something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In racket you may override `#%top`:

```scm
#lang racket

(provide
 (combine-out
  (except-out (all-from-out racket) #%top)
  (rename-out [shell-curry #%top])))

(require racket/system)

(define (stringify a)
  (~a (if (cmd? a) (cmd-name a) a)))

(struct cmd (name proc)
  #:property prop:procedure
  (struct-field-index proc)
  #:transparent
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc x port mode)
     (display (string-append "#<cmd:" (stringify x) ">") port))])

(define (shell name)
  (define (cmd-proxy . args)
    (define cmd
      (string-join (map stringify (cons name args))
                   " "))
    (system cmd))
  cmd-proxy)

(define-syntax shell-curry
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ . id)
     (cmd 'id (shell 'id)))))
```

Save this as shell.rkt and make this runner.rkt in the same directory:

```scm
#lang s-exp "shell.rkt"

(define test (list /bin/ls /usr/bin/file))
(second test) ; ==> #<cmd:/usr/bin/file>
(first test)  ; ==> #<cmd:/bin/ls>
((second test) (first test)) 
; ==> t (prints that /bin/ls is an executable on my system)
```

Now from here to make it a `#lang myshell` or something like that is pretty easy.

Answer (score 9):

Common Lisp has a standard error system which may be used to implement that.

In Common Lisp implementations which provide a `use-value` or `store-value` restart for errors of type `undefined-function`.

**Example**

```
CL-USER 69 > (flet ((call-use-value-restart (c)
                      (use-value (lambda (arg)
                                   (format t "~%dummy function with arg ~a~%" arg))
                                 c)))
               (handler-bind ((undefined-function #'call-use-value-restart))
                 (this-function-does-not-exist "foo")))

dummy function with arg foo
NIL
```

In the above example the function `this-function-does-not-exist` does not exist. As you can see, the error is handled and another function is called instead, which then does some output.

If we call the undefined function on its own, we get an error:

```
CL-USER 70 > (this-function-does-not-exist "foo")

Error: Undefined operator THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST in form (THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST "foo").
  1 (continue) Try invoking THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST again.
  2 Return some values from the form (THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST "foo").
  3 Try invoking something other than THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST with the same arguments.
  4 Set the symbol-function of THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST to another function.
  5 Set the macro-function of THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST to another function.
  6 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 71 : 1 >
```

Our example basically calls the restart number 3 programmatically:

It binds a handler which calls the function `call-use-value-restart` when an error of type `undefined-function` happens.

The function `call-use-value-restart` then calls the `use-value` restart with a function it provides. Here you could provide a function which calls an external program of the name given by `(cell-error-name c)`. The `use-value` restart then just calls the provided function and keeps on executing the program as usual.

**Hint for a solution**

Typically one would write a small top-level loop where such a handler is provided.

**Another way to call the restart**

In this example we use a *hook* to add a handler in case an error happens. Here we use the global variable `*debugger-hook*`. This should be a function and in our case it calls a new function when the condition `c` is of type `undefined-function`.

```
* (defun provide-a-function-hook (c hook)
    (declare (ignore hook))
    (typecase c
      (undefined-function (use-value (lambda (arg)
                                       (format t "~%dummy function with arg ~a~%" arg))
                                     c))))
PROVIDE-A-FUNCTION-HOOK

* (setf *debugger-hook* #'provide-a-function-hook)
#<FUNCTION PROVIDE-A-FUNCTION-HOOK>

* (this-function-does-not-exist "foo")
; in: THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST "foo"
;     (THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST "foo")
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     THIS-FUNCTION-DOES-NOT-EXIST
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

dummy function with arg foo
NIL
```

Comment: Great! I accept racket version now. I will try to make a common lisp implementation and come back with a comment how it went.